# IntelIJ module doesn't show test source root

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, testng

I have project with many modules and recently added new one, but IntelIJ doesn't recognise source test root inside module when I try to add it in TestNG xml.

I tried:

1. Invalidate and restart
2. Mark and unmark folder
3. Build project
4. Clean install
5. Delete module and create new one

On picture you can see one module is ok, but second have only main source root

[image]

Comment: Please tell if the module is Maven/Gradle? Thanks

Comment: This is a maven module

Comment: could you pls specify your version of IDEA and which steps you follow to get the dialog on your screenshot?